# Bingads SDK Python Suds sending wrong envelope

Tags: python, suds, bing-ads-api

Using BingAds SDK for Python I am not able to perform any operation to update because of a bug that I cannot resolve.
The SDK uses Suds for the handling of SOAP operation.

Here is the wsdl:
https://campaign.api.bingads.microsoft.com/Api/Advertiser/CampaignManagement/v13/CampaignManagementService.svc?singleWsdl

```
# This function internally configures the authorization for BingAdsAPI
campaign_service = bc.get_bing_ads_client(account=account, service='CampaignManagementService')

update_ad_groups_request = campaign_service.factory.create('UpdateAdGroupsRequest')
update_ad_groups_request.CampaignId = campaign_id

ad_group = campaign_service.factory.create('AdGroup')
ad_group.Id = ad_group_id

bid = campaign_service.factory.create('Bid')

bid.Amount = new_bid
ad_group.CpcBid = bid

update_ad_groups_request.AdGroups = campaign_service.factory.create('ArrayOfAdGroup')

update_ad_groups_request.AdGroups.AdGroup.append(ad_group)

campaign_service.UpdateAdGroups(update_ad_groups_request)
```

When I send it it fails saying:

> suds.WebFault: Server raised fault: 'The formatter threw an exception
>   while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while
>   trying to deserialize parameter
>   https://bingads.microsoft.com/CampaignManagement/v13:CampaignId. The
>   InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the
>   object of type System.Int64. The value '' cannot be parsed as the type
>   'Int64'.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.'

When I open the soap Envelope:

```
....</SOAP-ENV:Header><ns1:Body><ns0:UpdateAdGroupsRequest><ns0:CampaignId>
<ns0:CampaignId>377072652</ns0:CampaignId><ns0:AdGroups><ns0:AdGroup><ns0:CpcBid>
<ns0:Amount>0.91</ns0:Amount></ns0:CpcBid><ns0:Id>1256742239729725</ns0:Id>
<ns0:Network/><ns0:PrivacyStatus/><ns0:Status/></ns0:AdGroup></ns0:AdGroups>
</ns0:CampaignId></ns0:UpdateAdGroupsRequest></ns1:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Note how the Campaign ID is twice and also it wraps the whole envelope. I tried also directly with Suds and I have the same issue, other functions also have the same issue.

Because moving to parsing the envelopes by myself, I was wondering if someone has had this issue and what could be the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need to explicitly create a 'Request' object i.e., via the SUDS service client you can pass the request parameters directly via the UpdateAdGroups operation. To confirm I started with [expanded_text_ads.py](https://github.com/BingAds/BingAds-Python-SDK/blob/master/examples/v13/expanded_text_ads.py) and inserted the following snippet immediately after the [AddAdGroups](https://github.com/BingAds/BingAds-Python-SDK/blob/master/examples/v13/expanded_text_ads.py#L64) example.

```py
ad_groups=campaign_service.factory.create('ArrayOfAdGroup')
ad_group=set_elements_to_none(campaign_service.factory.create('AdGroup'))
ad_group.Id=ad_group_ids['long'][0]
cpc_bid=campaign_service.factory.create('Bid')
cpc_bid.Amount=0.11
ad_group.CpcBid=cpc_bid
ad_groups.AdGroup.append(ad_group)

output_status_message("-----\nUpdateAdGroups:")
add_ad_groups_response=campaign_service.UpdateAdGroups(
    CampaignId=campaign_ids['long'][0],
    AdGroups=ad_groups
)
output_status_message("PartialErrors:")
output_array_of_batcherror(add_ad_groups_response.PartialErrors)
```

I hope this helps! Please let me know if you have any follow up questions.